# Which armor/weapon type is the strongest to forge?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I like to relay on my own forged armor and custom enchants it giving it a more personal touch since i spent all that cash/time buying/collecting the items needed to make the armor

I got Deadric and Dragonbone smithing perks and looking at the initial stats of the armors Deadric has a greater value despite that Dragonbone needed a Blacksmithing skill of 100 to unlock the perk.

My Flawless Platemail has been beating initial Orcish armor for a while so knowing that i can further improve Dragonbone and Deadric Armor, with a Blacksmithing skill of 100, no potions to boost and being able to improve armor/weapons right after i forge them, i am wondering which armor/weapon set is more powerful to forge, Deadric and Dragonbone

NOTE 1: i use a one-handed sword (ie. Blades katana) so for comparison between Deadric and Dragonbone sets only compare one-handed swords, not maces or axes

NOTE 2: the enchantments on my armor don't boost resistances to attacks (they mainly boost Mana regeneration and Carry Weight) and my sword always has a 1 second Soul Trap so answers should avoid possible increases to attack/armor rating done via enchantments

NOTE 3: an answer doesn't need to be all Deadric/Dragonbone or even include them (as i am just going by the last 2 perks in the Blackmithing Skill), it just need to include Armour i can make in any forge and further improve at the armor bench/grind stone

Comment: @z' ahhhh, when i put in the title for my question i saw that but it said *best obtainable* so i assumed it was encompassing unique loot aswell however looking at the answers it seems the answer is always crafted armor, however it does include steps for boosting the effects with enchanting/potions, i can accept the answers there if Deadric armor is still better even without potions/enchanting

Comment: if you have enough blacksmithing, then it doesn't matter what armor you wear since you can reach the maximum armor cap with any piece via smithing.

Comment: Improved Daedric Armor.